# Will a cart mounted with a rotating wheel with axis inline with chassis's center axis move forward due to direction of angular momentum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

[image]Imagine a four-wheeled cart with a heavy metallic wheel rotating clockwise around a central axis fitted on its chassis. Will the direction of Angular velocity propel the cart ahead without providing any direct power to its four wheels?

Comment: This is not a home-like question, but it is a real question based on direction of Angular velocity/momentum.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to explain why you'd expect there to be an effect?  The answer is almost certainly "no", but I'd rather not post an answer without explaining where the misconception is.  (It's also possible that I'm misunderstanding your idea, so you might also want to be more specific about the setup that you have in mind;  a diagram would be ideal.)

Comment: Hi @MichaelSeifert,

I couldn't upload an image (or could not find way to do so).

A matching image would be of a hovercraft where instead of blower a Flywheel rotating in clockwise direction when seen standing on the platform towards the wheel. Two axles attached to the hovercraft platform with powerless wheels like a cart. Hope that explains the setup.

Comment: When you edit the question, there should be an icon that looks like a picture of a mountain in the editing toolbar.  Clicking on that will allow you to insert a picture into your post.  Also, when you edit, please elaborate on why you think there would be an effect.